# Google Custom-Search-Ads: When and why it is needed to use maxTop?

Tags: adsense, google-custom-search

According to the adsense documentation, maxTop is "Required when the ad unit is above the search results. Use this parameter to specify the number of ads to be shown on the top ad unit."

https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/s/docs/reference

Why do we need to do so? What if there are contents, little or lengthy, before the TOP ad? Is this still required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxTop` isn't *technically* required, but when you use that instead of `number` it tells CSA that that block is the TOP block.  The TOP block is generally more valuable since it's more likely to be seen so it's best to tell the system when you have a block like that.

If you have some content before it (a nav bar, search bars, etc) that's probably fine.  If you have a lot of content before it such that the user would have to scroll to see the ads then `maxTop` probably doesn't make sense.

Both `number` and `maxTop` will act as the max number of ads that should be shown in that block.  The only difference is that it lets the system know which block is on the top of the page, and `maxTop` can only be used on the first block in the page.  If you have multiple blocks all others must use `number`, regardless of what you use for the first block.